# Ubuntu "Monitor Out Of Range"

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, usb, monitor

I want to put Ubuntu onto my pen drive of 32 gigs. I have another 16 gig pendrive that I created as an Ubuntu bootable drive.

Whenever I run my PC with the USB inside the port, It automatically boots up into the "Try Ubuntu, etc." screen and gives me 5 seconds to choose an option. After I press enter on "Try Ubuntu Without Installing" instantly my monitor goes black and then the "Input Signal out of Range" message pops up.

I know its an old monitor which can support up to 1280x720 but I prefer 1152x864.

I cannot buy a new monitor so I am stuck with the one I have. I just want to create an Ubuntu desktop on my flash drive but I cannot seem to actually make it work on my PC.

I am installing Ubuntu Budgie LTS version as of 8/4/19.

File is:
ubuntu-budgie-18.04.2-desktop-amd64

Answer (score 0):

Try passing boot parameter `vga=xxx` (in your case i suggest vga=791, so 1024x768, 16 bit color).

See vga numbers in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers

Comment: So do I just straight away type vga=xxx or do I have to press any other key. Also by boot you mean after the input message appears or before it

Comment: press e when grub menu is showing the right boot environment.